# strange behavior of matplotlib in a jupyter ipython notebook

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create plots in a qt widget but am having problems

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

then

```
matplotlib qt
```

if I do the next two commands in the same cell

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(11)
```

all goes well.  If I separate the last two commands into two cells, I only get a qt window and not plot.  Same thing if I do the object style of plotting

I am running Python 3.10.5, matplotlib 3.5.3, ipykernel 6.15.1, ipython 8.4.0 and qtconsole 5.3.1 (I am having similar problems getting an active qtconsole from inside a notebook, probably related to the matplotlib qt problem).

I do not have this problem in an ipython console or a qtconsole (called from the command line) but these do not have cells.

On another computer, I am running Python 3.6 and do not have this.

thanks for your interest

Comment: _**if I do the next two commands in the same cell**_ is the expected behavior. Don't put them in separate cells.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem went away.  I run Opensuse linux with the tumbleweed distribution that is continually being updated.  Tried an old notebook and the problem had disappeared